# GIT clone - failure and deleted the target folder

Tags: git, windows-server-2003, network-share, nas

I am trying to do a GIT clone (I am new to GIT)

The command I use is:

```
C:\GIT>git clone --bare \\NAS1\GIT\OptiTexRepo \\backupnas\backup\GIT
```

Inside the \BACKUPNAS during the run I get several folders created. When they end, I get an error in my CMD windows

```
Cloning into bare repository \\backupnas\backup\GIT...
fatal: '\optitexnas\GIT\OptiTexRepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

And the folder on BACKUPNAS is deleted.

Running with --verbose does not add any new data to the screen.

What am I missing please?
What should the correct syntax be if I want to create a backup of my GITREPO?

- The GITREPO is located on a shared folder in our NAS (Readynas 1100 by Netgear)
- The server I run the command from has GIT installed and is a W2K3

EDIT:
It looks like the entire project is been copied, and at the end (after all the files are copied, I get the error message0 and than the entire directory is deleted again.

Comment: It looks like the the path to the repository you're trying to clone is wrong.  git creates the directory structure in preparation for the clone but then can't find any data to clone so it deletes the target directory tree.

Comment: What should be the path than? My main repdirectory is: \\NAS1\GIT\ Under that I have several repositories: OptiTexRepo, LibREPO, etc.. thanks, each repository ofc has it's own folder structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `OptiTexRepo` is really a repository:

Always use **forward slashes** for network paths when accessing them with `msysgit`:

```
git clone --bare //NAS1/GIT/OptiTexRepo //backupnas/backup/GIT
```

This should clone `OptiTexRepo` into your `backupnas`.

Furthermore, in your comment on your question, you write that you have several repos present on `NAS1` that you might back up. So it would be a good idea to give the clone a meaningful name:

```
git clone --bare //NAS1/GIT/OptiTexRepo //backupnas/backup/GIT/OptiTexRepo.git
```

Another point: just cloning will put the current state of `OptiTexRepo` to `backupnas`, but does not backup future states of the repo. The best way of backing up a git repo is working with it:

- `git clone //NAS1/Git/OptiTexRepo D:/OptiTex` will create a working copy under `D:/OptiTex`
- work and `git commit` in this repo (`D:/OptiTex`)
- occasionally push your changes to the NAS using `git push --mirror origin`
- Hey presto! Created a backup of `D:/OptiTex` on `//NAS1/Git/OptiTexRepo`